# Customising BrainTree Drop UI

Tags: reactjs, payment, braintree

I am using Braintree Drop Ui in my react application. Can anybody help me out how to customize the UI because its looking to ugly

Answer (score 0):

See how to customize your UI e.g. via CSS or field overrides in the ["Customize your UI" section of the official documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/customization/javascript/v3#customize-your-ui).

If that doesn't fit your needs you can also edit the UI on the client side. E.g. to customize the headings use `document.getElementsByClassName("braintree-heading")` and set the *style* attributes of its items.